# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGSvgView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

I am on a React Native project, I tried to use chart related dependencies in my project, and I have tried `@rainbow-me/animated-charts` and `react-native-wagmi-charts`, and all of them leads to the same error `Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSVGSvgView" was not found in the UIManager.` I am stucked for 24 hours, and do not know how to proceed. Could anyone provide any clue of how to resolving this?  Thank you very much in advance.

Blow are my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tradingbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rainbow-me/animated-charts": "^1.0.0-alpha.6",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "expo": "^49.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-router": "2.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.5.1",
    "react-native-wagmi-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Below are the output of running `npm why react-native-svg`:

```
react-native-svg@12.5.1
node_modules/react-native-svg
  react-native-svg@"^12.5.1" from the root project
  react-native-svg@"^12.1.0" from @rainbow-me/animated-charts@1.0.0-alpha.6
  node_modules/@rainbow-me/animated-charts
    @rainbow-me/animated-charts@"^1.0.0-alpha.6" from the root project
  peer react-native-svg@"*" from react-native-wagmi-charts@2.3.0
  node_modules/react-native-wagmi-charts
    react-native-wagmi-charts@"^2.3.0" from the root project
```

My babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
      require.resolve('expo-router/babel'),
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolve it by using 'npx expo install react-native-svg' not 'npm i react-native-svg'

now 'react-native-wagmi-charts' works, and '@rainbow-me/animated-charts' shows another error